# Bold text in php output

Tags: php, text, woocommerce

I would like only **Registration ID:** to be bolded. I tried inserting `<b>` tags before and after in separate quotes but it broke everything.

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'Registration ID: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean "broke everything"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can had the bold tags to your printf format.

```
<p><?php printf('<b>Registration ID:</b> %s', '124125'); ?></p>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#format